# How to remove items from supabase if I already ingested them?

Tags: supabase

My project is setup a lot like this: https://supabase.com/blog/loading-data-supabase-python

I have a python script that ingests things into my prod db. Recently, I edited the script to add some more things to the database, but I added too many and now I want to remove some of them. The script runs in prod via a refresh.yml workflow. If I just push my project normally, the script runs, but it just updates the items that are already in there and doesn't remove the things that I am no longer adding in my script. Do I need to reset my prod db? How do people usually go about this without taking their whole website down?